# Flickity - Flexbox Issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox, flickity

I have an issue with my images within flickity slider with flexbox using @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px)

It seems it applies the flexbox width 50% which it should on the flickity slider/carousel-cells making(see attached img)two of the images/cells not taking up the space they should(width:100%). It should apply the flexbox on the container but not the slider I guess :/

Could really need some help on this, thanks! the website: https://menso2203.github.io/test_12/

[image]

```css
   .cases._is_accent .cases__item-QUAN,
      .cases._is_inhalf .cases__item-QUAN {
          -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          width: 50%;
          -webkit-box-flex: 0;
          -ms-flex-positive: 0;
          flex-grow: 0;
          -ms-flex-negative: 0;
          flex-shrink: 0;
          padding-left: 0px;
          padding-right: 0px;
    
      }
    
    .main-page{
        position: relative;
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        z-index: 10;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 40px 40px;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
        padding-top:1px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .container {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    
    }
    
    .cases {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-bottom: -25px;
    
    }
```

```html
<div class="main-page">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="_has_mt _is_accent cases _is_inhalf">
            <div class="box cases__item-QUAN">
              <div class="main-carousel" data-flickity='{ "autoPlay": 2000 }'>
    
    <div class="box cases__item">
        <div class="box__img image-container">
           <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="Images/OnceUponANow_2020/QUAN_001.png" alt="NAME"  class="image-scale-QUAN-01  lazyloaded" class="lazyload" loading="lazy"></div>
    
             <div class="box__label">3D PRODUCTION</div></div>
               <a class="box__href" href="#">
                <span>Once Upon A Now</span></a>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="box cases__item">
        <div class="box__img image-container">
           <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="Images/OnceUponANow_2020/QUAN_002.png" alt="NAME"   class="image-scale-QUAN-02  lazyloaded" class="lazyload" loading="lazy"></div>
             <div class="box__label">3D PRODUCTION</div></div>
               <a class="box__href" href="#">
                <span>Once Upon A Now</span></a>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="box cases__item">
        <div class="box__img image-container">
           <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="Images/OnceUponANow_2020/QUAN_003.png" alt="NAME"  class="image-scale-QUAN-03  lazyloaded" class="lazyload" loading="lazy"></div>
             <div class="box__label">3D PRODUCTION</div></div>
               <a class="box__href" href="#">
                <span>Once Upon A Now</span></a>
    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```